# Promise.all() returning all results as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am building up an array of promises from Mongoose's `Model.save()`  But for some reason the returned data from `Promise.all()` is an array of undefined

**Code**

```
const saveDataArray = [];
//go through results and save them to the db
Object.keys(passData.scrapeUniqueData).map((index) => {
    const result = gamesExport.addGame(passData.scrapeUniqueData[index], passData.leagueInfo.league_id, passData.leagueInfo.leagueID, passData.leagueInfo.year);
    if(result)
    saveDataArray.push(result);
});

//const -> saveDataArray 
[Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise,  Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]

return Promise.all(saveDataArray)
.then((savedDBData) => {
    console.info('savedDBData', savedDBData);
    console.info('saveDataArray', saveDataArray);
    passData.savedDBGames = savedDBData.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined });
    return passData;
})

//const -> savedDBData 
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

So imo `savedDBData` should be returning the same as `saveDataArray. Why isn't Promise.all returning the data that was saved?

**AddGame**

```
addGame: (details, league_id, leagueID, year) => {
    "use strict";
    if(!details.result && details.result[0] === "P"){
        console.error('result skipped for postponded match');
        return;
    }
    if (details && details.notes !== "Postponed" && !details.postponed) {
        var result = new Games();
        result.fixtureID = details.fixtureID;

        if (details.date.toString().indexOf('z') === -1) {
            result.date = Date.parse(moment(details.date.toString(), "DD-MM-YYYY H:m").format());
        } else {
            result.date = details.date;
        }
        result.home_id = details.home_id._id;
        result.away_id = details.away_id._id;
        result.league_id = league_id;
        result.leagueID = leagueID;
        result.year = year;
        result.norsemen = details.home_id.name.isNorsemen() || details.away_id.name.isNorsemen();

        if (details.result) {
            if (details.result.home === "A" && details.result.away === "A") {
                result.result = ['A', 'A'];
                result.postponed = true;
            } else if (details.result.home === "H" && details.result.away === "W") {
                result.result = ['H', 'W'];
            } else if (details.result.home === "A" && details.result.away === "W") {
                result.result = ['A', 'W'];
            } else if (details.result.home === "C" && details.result.away === "C") {
                result.result = ['C', 'C'];
                result.cancelled = true;
            } else if (details.result.home === "P" && details.result.away === "P") {
                result.result = ['P', 'P'];
                result.postponed = true;
            } else {
                result.result = [parseInt(details.result.home), parseInt(details.result.away, 10)];
            }
        }
        return result.save(function (err, saveData) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            return result;
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    }
},
```

Comment: Have you already tested that `result.then( data => console.dir(data))` within your map, really resolves to something different then `undefined`? I would assume that the error is already within  `addGame`.

Comment: It actually depends on the resolution of `addGame`. Can you do `saveDataArray[0].then( console.log )`. If you have undefined there, your logic is correct.

Comment: Ah, I'm returning a `promise` but the returned value of promise is empty!! arghh silly. Although I am confused as to why its empty

Comment: @JamieHutber If you want us to help you on that you need to post your `addGame` code

Comment: Updated, I see there are 2 closes for this question... Maybe I should close it if its not helpful to anybody?

Comment: A promise resolving to `undefined` is typically caused by forgetting to return a result from a `then` callback.

Comment: What does `Game.save` do?

Comment: Game.save returns the promise. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html Game.save is just a mongoose model. Model.save in other words.
`Mongoose async operations, like .save() and queries, return Promises/A+ conformant promises. This means that you can do things like MyModel.findOne({}).then() and yield MyModel.findOne({}).exec() (if you're using co)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a callback function to a Mongoose method, it assumes that you won't be using the promise that it returns as well.

I'm not sure if this is by design (I guess it is, because otherwise both the regular callback and the promise handler will be called, with the same result), but I can reproduce your issue with code that looks like this:

```
let doc = new Model(...);
doc.save((err, res) => {
  console.log('CB RES', res);
}).then(res => {
  console.log('PR RES', res);
});
```

`PR RES` (*"promise result"*) is logged with a result of `undefined`, but `CB RES` (*"callback result"*) logs a proper document. When you don't pass a callback function to `save()`, then `PR RES` logs the proper document.

So you should rewrite `addGame` to just return a promise, and not pass in a callback function:

```
return result.save().catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  // XXX: be aware that if you don't do anything else here,
  //      the error will _just_ be logged, but not propagated.
  //      This is also what your original code does, so I assume
  //      it's intentional.
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you mate.